# python Elasticsearch difficulty to go from SQL to ES format of request

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am going crazy with the ES system for requesting information.

I have something like:

```
select * from mytable where (group like('%ABC%') or group like ('%DEF%')) and startdate > "2020-02-27 00:00:00"
```

and cannot understand how to translate that in the ES language. I spend the last day on it and I think I need some examples (and reading) to understand...

Ho please, help!

Answer (score 0):

if using API just make json object and use POST to elasticSearch server. if do at python is it not so hard

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "group": "%ABC%"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "group": "%DEF%"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "startdate": {
                            "gte": "2020-02-27 00:00:00"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 1000
}
```